# CSS - Rows and Columns arrangement

Tags: html, css

I am creating a site that has news and would like to style it like a reddit news box. It would look something like the following. I am using angular material and css, so basically pure HTML and CSS, no bootstrap or anything of the like.

```
_____________________________________
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 1        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 2        |
|_____________________________________|
|Coulmn 1  |  Column2 - Area 3        |
______________________________________
```

I've played around with different versions using display: flex, but can't quite get it arranged properly. Can anyone help out?

I've tried

```
<div class="news-container">
  <div class="news-header">
    <div class="news-vote-column">
      <div>
        <mat-icon matSuffix color="accent" class="clickable-icon" (click)="voteUp()">arrow_drop_up</mat-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="vote-number">1</div>
      <div>
        <mat-icon matSuffix color="accent" class="clickable-icon" (click)="voteDown()">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
     <div>
      <h3>I am a new post!</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h5>- Posted by admin - 10/10/2019 12:00</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</div> 

.news-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  border: #7e868d 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.news-vote-column {
  min-height: 200px;
  min-width: 40px;
  background-color: #d2d3d6;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.news-header {
  display: flex;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  color: #7e868d;
  h3 {
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
  }

  h5 {
    color: #cecfd1;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.vote-number {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.clickable-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free coding service. You're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For further information, please see [how to ask,](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: i would look into grid here, but no code , nor attempt shown to get your real question here :(

Comment: I put some stuff in the question relating to what I am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to fiddle something together: https://jsfiddle.net/dtq1p0w4/

```
<div class="news-container">
  <div class="news-vote-column">
    <div>
      <mat-icon matSuffix color="accent" class="clickable-icon" (click)="voteUp()">arrow_drop_up</mat-icon>
    </div>
    <div class="vote-number">1</div>
    <div>
      <mat-icon matSuffix color="accent" class="clickable-icon" (click)="voteDown()">arrow_drop_down</mat-icon>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="news-header">
      <h3>I am a new post!</h3>
      <h5>- Posted by admin - 10/10/2019 12:00</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="news-content">
      I am news content!
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

.news-container {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  background-color: #f1f2f3;
  border: #7e868d 1px solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-height: 200px;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Tahoma, sans-serif;
  display: flex;
}

.news-vote-column {
  min-width: 40px;
  background-color: #d2d3d6;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

.news-header {
  display: flex;
  color: #7e868d;
  h3 {
    margin: 2px 2px 2px 10px;
  }

  h5 {
    color: #cecfd1;
    margin: 5px;
  }
}

.vote-number {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2px 2px 2px 2px;
}

.clickable-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.news-content {
   margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this solution : 
https://jsfiddle.net/YvanBarbaria/a82ub30p/

I used flex box to position your div. Quick solution but I think suit what you want. You can easily loop on you angular template on the div with the "col" class.

```
<div class="cols-container">
  <div class="col">
    <div class="col1">
      <span>
        Column
      </span>
      <span>
        1
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col2">
        <div class="col2-name">
          <span>
            Column
          </span>
          <span>
            2
          </span>
        </div>
         <div class="col2-area">
          <span>
            Area 1
          </span>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


.cols-container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  .col {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    width: 100%;

    .col1 {
       flex-grow:1;
    }
    .col2 {
       flex-grow:1;
       display: flex;
       .col2-name {
         flex-grow:1;
       }
        .col2-area {
         flex-grow:1;
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this puts everything on one row, which is what I already have happening.

Comment: Yeah I produce the code for just one row like your design. `|Column 1  |  Column2 - Area 1        |`  and like I told you, you have to loop for create all the other row.  Something like that  ` <div class="col" *ngFor="let row of rows">`

Comment: Please provide me a Stackblitz and I will help you. You are not very clear about what you want so the best way is to show me you entire code.